# Добавление List-a в List как объекта

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, foreach

У меня есть сервис который получает `Equipment` по `username`. И в контроллере есть метод, который выводит во View `Equipment` у роли `Manager` и `Users`.

Модель `Equipment`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "equipment")
public class Equipment {

    private int id;
    private String brand;
    private String model;
    private String inventoryNumber;
    private String serialNumber;
    private String type;
    private String note;
    private User user;
```

Модель `Users`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NamedQuery(name = "allUsers", query = "SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Department department;
    private boolean enabled;
    private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<UserRole>();
    private Set<Equipment> equipment = new HashSet<Equipment>();
```

Метод контроллера:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/manager", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    private ModelAndView manager() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String name = auth.getName();
        User user = userService.findByName(name);
        String username = user.getUsername();
        List<Equipment> managerEquip = equipmentService.findByUser(username);
        Department department = user.getDepartment();
        List<User> depUsers = userService.findByDepartment(department);
        for (User users : depUsers){
            String depUsername = users.getUsername();
            userEquip = equipmentService.findByUser(depUsername);
            }
        model.addObject("userEquip", userEquip);
        model.addObject("managerDep", managerEquip);
        model.setViewName("manager");
        return model;
    }
```

У роли `Manager` список `Equipment` в представление выводится нормально и у роли `Users` тоже, если вписывать от руки, то выводит. И еще `username`-ы он правильно находит все. Отдельно выводил логины, все работает. А вот когда мне нужно чтоб по всем `Users` выводил, он не выводит. Мне кажется проблема в цикле. Он находит `equipmentService.findByUser(depUsername);` только по последнему `username`. Как мне сделать, чтоб цикл каждый раз записывал сверху, а не перезаписывал на предыдущую запись?

Comment: я 3 раза перечитал, но так и не понял что и куда у вас выводится.

Comment: Сделал исправления. Теперь понятно?

Comment: Я не вижу где у вас задаётся переменная `userEquip` она глобальная? Если так то плохо у вас не потоко-безопасное приложение. Вообще, если я правильно понял, то вам надо отдельный список(например ArrayList) и туда складывать через addAll

Comment: private List<Equipment> userEquip;

Comment: @Vartlok Я пытался сделать таким образом, но тогда выдает ошибку NullPointException. Точно не знаю, как создать отдельный список и как складывать. Я в этом направлении думал, но не получилось. Может с этим поможете и проблема решится?

Comment: `List<Equipment> userEquip = new ArrayList<Equipment>` - перед циклом

Comment: Он опять выводит только последний результат. А все остальные перезаписывает.

Comment: Что значит последний? Судя по вашему методу он выводи одно и тоже всегда, т.к. в него не передаются никакие параметры.

Comment: что с этим for-ом не так?  `for (User users : depUsers){ ... }` ? каков его смысл? перезаписывать постоянно этот список?
замени на `userEquip.addAll(equipmentService.findByUser(depUsername));` А так это вообще бред какой то, используй аннотации `@OneToMany` и `@ManyToOne` что бы не проделавать кучу ненужных операцый которй `hibernate` должен делать за тебя

Comment: Спасибо @GVArt Я присваивал, а надо было как вы сказали и как сказал ранее Vartlok addAll делать. Только я делал его неправильно, а вы показали как надо правильно. Спасибо вам обоим )